# Trying to measure/anticipate the time that an agent would to take to get to the current checkpoint (the checkpoints get spawned randomly)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agent, checkpoint

The script isn't working as I want..

float distanceToCheckpoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, checkpointPosition);

```
float actualTimeToReachCheckpoint = distanceToCheckpoint/speed * Time.deltaTime;

float extraTimeGivenToAgentToCheckpoint = actualTimeToReachCheckpoint * 1.5f;

elapsedTime = Time.deltaTime;

if(elapsedTime >= actualTimeToReachCheckpoint || elapsedTime <= extraTimeGivenToAgentToCheckpoint){ //rest of script
```

}

I am trying to calculate the time the agent would take to get to the current checkpoint without any delays (like anticipating) I'm giving it some extra time to get to the checkpoint but if doesn't then I will end the episode - I'm completely new to this and I don't know if the script I made it any good. This is mt script..

as you can see, I have 2 variables, one is for the actual and anticipated time that the agent should supposedly take to get to the current checkpoint although I'm giving it some extra time in case of any delays.
in the if statement I want to check if the elapsed time is equal to or less than the anticipated time, or the extra time given. I have a suspect that the issue is because I'm not converting the units which represent the distance to time properly! I'm guessing!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) if you have trouble identifying units:

1. distanceToCheckpoint - is a length (m)
2. speed  - is length by time (m/s)
3. actualTimeToReachCheckpoint  - time (s)
4. distanceToCheckpoint / speed  -> m / (m/s)

The 'm' cancel each other out, and '1 / (1/s)' = 's'. So this expression gives the time, no need to multiply with Time.deltaTime in this case.

Comment: I did that, but I don't think the result has changed.

Comment: I made a new script to approach the problem differently 
I made a new method and called in the initialize 
private void SetTarget()
    {
        float distanceToCheckpoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, checkpointPosition);

        actualTimeToReachCheckpoint = distanceToCheckpoint/speed * Time.deltaTime;

        float extraTimeGivenToAgentToCheckpoint = actualTimeToReachCheckpoint * 1.5f;
    }

Then made this in the updated method
  currentTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;

        if(currentTime > actualTimeToReachCheckpoint) {..}

Comment: @Mohammed-Student the only way removing the delta time would not change the results is if it is 1, and that is unlikely. Check that other assumptions hold, i.e. variables are correct, speed is constant, etc.

Comment: I will show u what I tried yesterday but it kept executing the code in my if statement although I still couldn't wrap my head around how the condition was being met
see the code: in the answer I'll add on this post because the comment section ha limited space and I cannot put all of the code!

Answer (score 0):

[Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) returns the interval in seconds from the last frame to the current one. Its value changes every frame. If you want to calculate the time needed for the agent to reach the target position, you need the distance that the agent can travel per second.

With that value and the total distance, you can calculate the seconds that the agent will need with `totalDistance/distanceTravelledPerSecond`. It is worth mentioning that [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) returns the distance as a straight line. If your agent moves not in a straight line, the estimation becomes inaccurate very quickly.

The more difficult part is the anticipation part of your question. ,,While the agent moves, will it still reach the target position within the previously calculated time limit?'' Changes to movement speed or movement direction have an impact here.

One approach to this problem could be to keep checking the distance between the agent and the target position and compare this to the distance that the agent should have moved already:

```
var remainingDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, checkpointPosition);
var expectedDistance = (totalDistance/distanceTravelledPerSecond) * secondsPassedSinceBeginning;
var threshold = 5;
bool arrivesInTime = (remainingDistance - expectedDistance) < threshold;
```

- `remainingDistance` is the distance that the agent still has to travel (again assumes the agent travelling a straight line).
- `expectedDistance` is the distance that you would expect the agent to have moved by now.
- `secondsPassedSinceBeginning` are the seconds that have passed since the agent started moving.
- `threshold` is the distance that is acceptable as a delay, here 5 distance units.

You can use [Time.time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) to get the specific point in time when something happens, storing it for later use.

Comment: I made a new script to approach the problem differently 
I made a new method and called in the initialize 
private void SetTarget()
    {
        float distanceToCheckpoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, checkpointPosition);

        actualTimeToReachCheckpoint = distanceToCheckpoint/speed * Time.deltaTime;

        float extraTimeGivenToAgentToCheckpoint = actualTimeToReachCheckpoint * 1.5f;
    }

Then made this in the updated method
  currentTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;

        if(currentTime > actualTimeToReachCheckpoint) {..}
is it any good?

Answer (score 0):

So @JonasH
As you can see below my code:

I made a new method and called it in the initialize/start

the speed of the agent is set to 5 already.
this approach didn't work as well.

```
public float speed = 5f; 
private float currentTime;
private float distanceToCheckpoint;
private float actualTimeToReachCheckpoint;
private float extraTimeGivenToAgentToCheckpoint;
private void SetTarget()
{
    float distanceToCheckpoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, checkpointPosition);

    actualTimeToReachCheckpoint = distanceToCheckpoint/agent.speed;

    float extraTimeGivenToAgentToCheckpoint = actualTimeToReachCheckpoint * 1.5f;
}
currentTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;

    if(currentTime > actualTimeToReachCheckpoint)
    {  
        //rest of code }
```

Comment: The currentTime +=1 * Time.deltaTime and the rest are in the update